# Extract zip Files on cmd with progress indicator

Tags: perl, command-line, progress-bar, unzip

I am looking for a program, which is able to extract zip archives via the windows commandline and that is able to display a progressbar or a percentage indicator on the cmd. I want to use this from within a Perl script and so give the user a hint how long the progress will take. I tried 7zip(http://www.7-zip.org/) and [Unzip(from InfoZIP)](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html) so far, but was not able to produce the behaviour described above. Does somebody know how to solve this?

Update:
Currently i'm trying it with this approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; $|++;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip;

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new('file.zip');
my $total_bytes = 0;
my $bytes_already_unzipped = 0;

foreach my $member ($zip->members()) {
    $total_bytes += $member->uncompressedSize();
}
foreach my $member ($zip->members()) {  
    $zip->extractMember($member);
    $bytes_already_unzipped += $member->uncompressedSize();
    print progress_bar($bytes_already_unzipped, $total_bytes, 25, '=' );
}

#routine by tachyon at http://tachyon.perlmonk.org/
#also have a look at http://oreilly.com/pub/h/943
sub progress_bar {
    my ( $got, $total, $width, $char ) = @_;
    $width ||= 25; $char ||= '=';
    my $num_width = length $total;
    sprintf "|%-${width}s| Got %${num_width}s bytes of %s (%.2f%%)\r", 
        $char x (($width-1)*$got/$total). '>', 
        $got, $total, 100*$got/+$total;
}
```

However i have two problems:

- this approach seems to be very slow
- i do not have a periodic update in the progress bar, but only when a file is finished beeing extracted. As i have some large files, the system seems to not respond while extracting them

Comment: I am currently trying to solve this by adding a subroutine, because i cant find a program.. I looked at Archive::Extract and i know how to get a status-bar. But i don't know how do determine the extracted filesize of the zip-file prior to extract the file.

Comment: Take a look at 7zip command line tool.

Comment: I did that, but there is no progress information available for unzipping, just for zipping. Furthermore it has a lot of output ("extracting /bla/foo.txt") that i cannot turn off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the extraction from within your program instead of delegating to a different one. Use [Archive::Zip](http://p3rl.org/Archive%3a%3aZip) and [Term::ProgressBar](http://p3rl.org/Term%3a%3aProgressBar). Extract files one by one. Update the progress after each.

Comment: Do you know how exactly managing it to extract files one by one? something like "foreach my $member($zip->members()){...}"?

Comment: ok got this: "foreach my $member($zip->members()){$zip->extractMember($member);}" does the job.

Comment: Thanks daxim! Finally did it as you mentioned. You can see the result above, but at the end i used Term::ProgressBar instead of the printf magic :)